# Creating Model Class in C#?

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, json.net

So I simply have a simple web API that returns JSON format as following

```
{
"dailyDealId": "432",
"discountPercentage": "0",
"product": {
    "productId": "10",
    "brandId": "10",
    "departmentId": "3",
    "name": "Baby Girl Velour Tunic & Snowflake Legging Set",
    "description": "The pretty set",
    "url": "http://whatever.whatever.com/files/whatever.tif"
}
```

}

I want to get this data on my C# console code

this is my Model Class Data.cs

```
class Data
{
    public string dailyDealId { get; set; }
    public string discountPercentage { get; set; }
    public Array product { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my main Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://whatever.com/");

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("product/").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
             var products = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Data>>().Result;

            foreach (var p in products)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("dailyDealId" + p.dailyDealId);
            }


        }

    }
```

But it doesnt seem to work and I get Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON Error, any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What's the content of the response? Does `http://whatever.com/product/` return nothing but json or do you have the wrong url?

Comment: the url is right, so when I call the url using POSTMAN or Soap ui it returns that JSON data that I put up there

Comment: You're calling an `asynchronous` method and expecting it to block whilst returning..

Comment: so how would you fix it?

Comment: `var products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Data>>().Result;` ???

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Accessing a Task result implicitly await.

Comment: I think my formatting has problem as I simply just want get this data like Soap UI does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One problem could be the fact that your class `Data` treat the member `product` as an `Array` when the JSON you are giving us as an example is an object (enclosed in `{}` not in `[]`).

You need to create a new class and change the type of `Data.product`:

```
public class Product
{
    public string productId { get; set; }
    public string brandId { get; set; }
    public string departmentId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string dailyDealId { get; set; }
    public string discountPercentage { get; set; }
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

`JsonConvert` should work with this definition.

Comment: how would you change the type of data?

Comment: I literaly gave you the type in my answer.